# Pandas plot function ignores timezone of timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

When plotting a timeseries with the built-in plot function of pandas, it seems to ignore the timezone of my index: it always uses the UTC time for the x-axis. An example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import rolling_mean, DataFrame, date_range

rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=200, freq='S', tz="UTC")
data = DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(rng), 3), index=rng, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
data_cet = data.tz_convert("CET")

# plot with data in UTC timezone
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data[["A", "B"]].plot(ax=ax, grid=True)
plt.show()

# plot with data in CET timezone, but the x-axis remains the same as above
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data_cet[["A", "B"]].plot(ax=ax, grid=True)
plt.show()
```

The plot does not change, although the index has:

```
In [11]: data.index[0]
Out[11]: <Timestamp: 2011-01-01 00:00:00+0000 UTC, tz=UTC>
In [12]: data_cet.index[0]
Out[12]: <Timestamp: 2011-01-01 01:00:00+0100 CET, tz=CET>
```

Should I file a bug, or do I miss something?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554146/2192488) is how this bug can be circumvented!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. I've created a report on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2106). The reason is because internally, pandas converts a regular frequency DatetimeIndex to PeriodIndex to hook into formatters/locators in pandas, and currently PeriodIndex does NOT retain timezone information.
Please stay tuned for a fix.

Comment: 4 years later... any fix?

Comment: 5 years later and [won't fix!](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2106#issuecomment-253302000)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pytz import timezone as ptz
import matplotlib as mpl
...
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, utc=True).tz_localize(tz=ptz('<your timezone>'))
...
mpl.rcParams['timezone'] = data.index.tz.zone
```

... after which matplotlib prints as that zone rather than UTC.

However! Note if you need to annotate, the x locations of the annotations will still need to be in UTC, *even whilst strings passed to data.loc[] or data.at[] will be assumed to be in the set timezone!*

For instance I needed to show a series of vertical lines labelled with timestamps on them:
(this is after most of the plot calls, and note the timestamp strings in sels were UTC)

```
sels = ['2019-03-21 3:56:28',
         '2019-03-21 4:00:30',
         '2019-03-21 4:05:55',
         '2019-03-21 4:13:40']
ax.vlines(sels,125,145,lw=1,color='grey') # 125 was bottom, 145 was top in data units
for s in sels:
    tstr = pd.to_datetime(s, utc=True)\
    .astimezone(tz=ptz(data.index.tz.zone))\
    .isoformat().split('T')[1].split('+')[0]
    ax.annotate(tstr,xy=(s,125),xycoords='data',
              xytext=(0,5), textcoords='offset points', rotation=90,
              horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')
```

This puts grey vertical lines at the times chosen manually in `sels`, and labels them in local timezone hours, minutes and seconds. (the `.split()[]` business discards the date and timezone info from the `.isoformat()` string).

But when I need to actually get corresponding values from data using the same `s` in `sels`, I then have to use the somewhat awkward:

```
data.tz_convert('UTC').at[s]
```

Whereas just

```
data.at[s]
```

Fails with a `KeyError` because pandas interprets `s` is in the `data.index.tz` timezone, and so interpreted, the timestamps fall outside of range of the contents of `data`

Answer (score 0):

## How to deal with UTC to local time conversion

```
import time
import matplotlib.dates
…
tz = pytz.timezone(time.tzname[0])
…
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.HourLocator(interval=1, tz=tz))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H', tz=tz))
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - just kept getting UTC times shown. Also tried `ax.xaxis_date(tz)` with no luck either. But I eventually found a solution, albeit awkward. (see below)